# Android performance issue while populating AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, performance, autocompletetextview, cyanogenmod

I have an AutoCompleteTextView I populate dynamically. I do this dynamically, because I have about 10000 proposals (streets) to show, so I split the list according to their first letter. Let's say somebody enters "a", I populate the Adapter with all streets beginning with "a". This works and is fast enough in emulator and it was fast enough on my old phone Android 2.1. Suddenly I recognized that the filling of the list is very slow. It takes about 10 seconds to populate. But I think it's not a problem of my code but a problem of my phone. Some time ago I upgraded to Android 2.3.7 with CyanogenMod 7.2.0-blade. I'm absolutely sure that I never had this problems before, because I would never had put some laggy implementation on production. I recognized something strange while I made a trace. All the performance is frittered away on a method called `TextUtils.hasArabicCharacters()`. See the cyan bars...

[image: performance issue]

I don't find anything about this method. TextUtils doesn't have hasArabicCharacters, so I guess it's some proprietary thing -> CyanogenMod? **If I trace the same code on any emulator, no method called 'hasArabicCharacters' is ever invoked** and the autocomplete behaviour is pretty fast. Tested under Android 2.1, 2.3.3 and 4.1.2 emulator.

This is the invocation chain (upwards):

> TextUtils.hasArabicCharacter() -> TextUtils.reshapeArabic() ->
>   Paint.measureText() -> Styled.drawDirectionalRun() ->
>   Styled.measureText() -> BoringLayout.isBoring() ->
>   TextView.onMeasure() -> View.measure() -> ListView.measureScrapChild()
>   -> ListView.measureHeightOfChildren() -> AutoCompleteTextView.buildDropdown() ->
>   AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown() ->
>   AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter() ->
>   AutoCompleteTextView.access$1700 ->
>   AutoCompleteTextView$PopulateDataSetObserver$1.run() ->
>   Handler.handleCallback() -> Handler.dispatchMessage()

This is how I populate my Adapter. Maybe there is some workaround I could apply. Any ideas?

**Activity:**

```
        final StreetArrayAdapter adapter = new StreetArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        autoCompleteTextView.setValidator(new Validator());
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(0);
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                streetInfoField.setText("");
            }
        });

        autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new StreetTextWatcher(adapter));

......

    class Validator implements AutoCompleteTextView.Validator {

        @Override
        public CharSequence fixText(CharSequence invalidText) {
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(CharSequence text) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Checking if valid: " + text);
            String[] streets = StreetNameFactory.getStreetsWithLetter(text.subSequence(0, 1).toString().toUpperCase(Locale.US));

            Arrays.sort(streets);
            if (Arrays.binarySearch(streets, text.toString()) >= 0) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

**StreetNameFactory.getStreetsWithLetter**

```
    public static String[] getStreetsWithLetter(String letter)  {
        Log.i(StreetNameFactory.class.getSimpleName(), "letter:" + letter);
        if ("A".equals(letter))  {
            return StreetNames.STREETS_A;
        }
        if ("Ä".equals(letter))  {
            return StreetNames.STREETS_A;
        }
        if ("B".equals(letter))  {
            return StreetNames.STREETS_B;
        }
.....
```

**StreetTextWatcher:**

```
public class StreetTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private final StreetArrayAdapter adapter;
    private boolean alreadyAdded = false;

    public StreetTextWatcher(StreetArrayAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //not used
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if (s.length() < 1)  {
            adapter.clear();

            alreadyAdded = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {           
        if (s.length() == 1) {
            populateAdapter(s);

            alreadyAdded = true;
        }
    }

    private synchronized void populateAdapter(CharSequence s) { 
        String charSequence = s.toString().toUpperCase(Locale.US);
        if (charSequence.startsWith("A") && !alreadyAdded)  {
            adapter.addAll(StreetNames.STREETS_A);
        }

        if (charSequence.startsWith("Ä") && !alreadyAdded)  {
            adapter.addAll(StreetNames.STREETS_A);
        }

        if (charSequence.startsWith("B") && !alreadyAdded)  {
            adapter.addAll(StreetNames.STREETS_B);
        }

        if (charSequence.startsWith("C") && !alreadyAdded)  {
            adapter.addAll(StreetNames.STREETS_C);
        }

        if (charSequence.startsWith("D") && !alreadyAdded)  {
            adapter.addAll(StreetNames.STREETS_D);
        }

        if (charSequence.startsWith("E") && !alreadyAdded)  {
            adapter.addAll(StreetNames.STREETS_E);
        }
        //more code....

        if (charSequence.startsWith("Z") && !alreadyAdded)  {
            adapter.addAll(StreetNames.STREETS_Z);
        }
        if (Pattern.matches("[1-9]", s.toString()) && !alreadyAdded)  {
            adapter.addAll(StreetNames.STREETS_NUMBERS);
        }
    }
}
```

**StreetArrayAdapter:**

```
public class StreetArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final String TAG = StreetArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public StreetArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public void addAll(String[] streets) {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN LIST FILL at: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
        for (String street : streets) {
            add(street);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "END LIST FILL at: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
    }
}
```

**STREETS_A, STREETS_B, STREETS_C** are just string arrays I assign.

**[UPDATE]**
I was able to find a nice workaround. I must not load the list when I enter the first letter. When I load the list after I typed at least 3 letters (StreetTextWatcher.onTextChange), I have no freeze and the dropdown is very fast again. Moreover the user probably doesn't even recognize the change.

Comment: `TextUtils.hasArabicCharacters()` is called from `TextUtils.reshapeArabic()`. What method is calling `TextUtils.reshapeArabic()` (under "Parents" in traceview)?

Comment: I added the invocation chain. See updated posting.

Comment: Which version of CyanogenMod?

Comment: CyanogenMod 7.2.0-blade

Comment: What device is this? Have you tried `ezGingerBread1.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a flaw of CyanogenMod 7.2.

Looking at the source code shows that in **every** (in your case) [`TextView.onMeasure()`](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/gb-release-7.2/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) call,  `BoringLayout.isBoring()` is called, which calls [`Styled.measureText()`](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/gb-release-7.2/core/java/android/text/Styled.java), which calls [`Styled.drawDirectionalRun()`](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/gb-release-7.2/core/java/android/text/Styled.java), which looks like a quite heavy method (it calls a lot of other methods too).

I think it can be hard to workaround this in your code. I was looking for some flag that maybe you can set to omit this heavy "arabic" methods, something like `setIsArabic(false)`, but I haven't found anything. Maybe you could replace bytecode of for example  `Styled.measureText()`, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966726/how-to-change-method-behaviour-through-reflection),  but it seems pretty time-consuming.

It looks like in newer version, for example CyanogenMod 10.1, the behaviour is different. So maybe just upgrade your CyanogenMod and the problem will dissapear.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'd rather not update to 10.1, because I want to have an older version of Android (due to app development). If I don't find a solution I can live with that if it's only a problem of CyanogenMod or especially this version of CyanogenMod.