# How to override the behavior of a class if I have only its object?

Tags: java

The question may be a stupid one to ask but, kindly help me on this.
I need to override the behavior of a class, but I will get only the object of it. 
Following is the code sample.

I want to use the method Util.newChildComponent(String id) itself in all the places.

```
class ParentComponent{
    public ParentComponent(String id){}
    protected void someBehavior(){}
}

class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent{
    public ChildComponent(String id){
        super(id);
    }
    protected void childsBehavior(){}
}

public class Util {
    public static ParentComponent newChildComponent(String id)
    {
        ParentComponent fc = new ChildComponent(id);
        // Initialize the object, and performs some common configuration.
        // Performs different operations on the generated child object.
        // The child class has many members apart from childsBehavior().
        return fc;
    }
}


// The above classes belongs to a jar, so I cannot edit the code.
// I need to use Util.newChildComponent(String id)
// But I need to override the behavior as mentioned below.
public void f1()
{
    // TODO: How to override childsBehavior() method using the object 
    // I have it in pc? Is it possible?
    // Util.newChildComponent(id) method decorates the ChildComponent
    // So I need to use the same object and just override childsBehavior() method only.
    ParentComponent pc = Util.newChildComponent("childId");

    // I need to achieve the result below
    /*
    ParentComponent pc = new ChildComponent(id){
            @Override
            protected void childsBehavior(){
                super.someBehavior();
                // Do the stuff here.
            }
        }; */
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to override `childsBehavior` but also use `Util.newChildComponent` to create the instance?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15966918/1154145

Comment: And ChildComponent is the one that you can not modify?

Comment: @milez All the three - ParentComponent, ChildComponent  & Util

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for a [DynamicObjectAdaptorFactory](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue108.html).

Here's a use of his excellent object.

```
static class ParentComponent {

    protected void someBehavior() {
        System.out.println("ParentComponent someBehavior");
    }
}

static class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {

    private ChildComponent(String id) {

    }

    protected void childsBehavior() {
        System.out.println("childsBehavior");
    }
}

public static class Util {

    public static ParentComponent newChildComponent(String id) {
        ParentComponent fc = new ChildComponent(id);
        // Initialize the object, and performs some common configuration.
        return fc;
    }
}

interface Parent {

    void someBehavior();

}

// The adaptor.
public static class Adapter implements Parent {

    final ParentComponent parent;

    private Adapter(ParentComponent pc) {
        this.parent = pc;
    }

    // Override the parent behaviour.
    public void someBehavior() {
        System.out.println("Adapter invoke someBehaviour()");
        parent.someBehavior();
        System.out.println("Adapter finished someBehaviour()");
    }

}

public void test() {
    ParentComponent pc = Util.newChildComponent("childId");
    Parent adapted = DynamicObjectAdapterFactory.adapt(pc, Parent.class, new Adapter(pc));
    adapted.someBehavior();
}
```

Prints:

```
Adapter invoke someBehaviour()
someBehavior
Adapter finished someBehaviour()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Java's Dynamic Proxy. This should allow you to change the behavior at runtime by creating invocation handlers to handle a call to a method. You can even then forward it to the original method if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a new class that extends the one with the method you want to change

```
public class MyClass extends ChildComponent {

    @Override
    protected void childsBehavior()
    {
     .....
    }

}
```

<s>Then in your code you can use casting, which is a feature we get to enjoy thanks to inheritance</s>

MyClass pc = (myClass) Util.newChildComponent("childId");

But then you would have to create the new object like so

```
MyClass pc = new MyClass("childId");
```

and do the configurations by hand that would have been done at `Util`. Unless you extend `Util` and crete a method that creates an object of `MyClass` and copy the configuration code there.

And now `pc` will have all the methods of `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent`, but the `childsBehavior` will be what you declared.

Comment: Although this works, I think writing a wrapper is a more appropriate approach here. Since it should be exactly the same class, except the behavior of 1 function and not a parent-child relationship.

Comment: this will return a ClassCastException at runtime, because you're trying to downcast to a different class..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the code that uses `Util` to instantiate the objects you need, you could rewrite the `Util` class with the behavior you need (i.e. instantiating  a class that extends `ChildComponent` with the overridden method), just remember to put it in a package of the same name in your project (so that the import of its clients doesn't change). This way no other code should change at all.