# Modify Java Random with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Java reflection is powerful, I know it can SET declared fields or invoke method with new parameters.
Now can we "hack" the Random class like below to be "true" everytime?
`System.out.println( java.lang.Math.random() == java.lang.Math.random() );`

Math.random()

```
    public static double random() {
        return RandomNumberGeneratorHolder.randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();}
```

And the nextDouble()

```
     public double nextDouble() {
        return (((long)(next(26)) << 27) + next(27)) * DOUBLE_UNIT;}
```

And I'm stuck here, these methods don't even use any parameter to tamper with and I don't know if Java reflection can mess around inside method. Is there anyway else to get the same Math.random() every time?

Comment: You can subclass `Random`.

Comment: This info is helping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966726/how-to-change-method-behaviour-through-reflection ?