# Force all intents used by third party libraries to be FLAG_IMMUTABLE android

Tags: java, c#, android, android-13

I have a project where we have to use third party libraries,
but in one of the libraries ,its showing error-
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the Pending Intent being mutable

I am aware of this issue, but to solve it I have to edit the library codes which i am not able to do as codes are not available publicly.

So question is, Is there any workaround for this,
Force all intents used by third party libraries to be FLAG_IMMUTABLE android.

Comment: You'll have to ask them to fix their `PendingIntent` code, if they haven't already.

Comment: @uncle_scroge you can try to use reflect to modify it, if the third party libraries not fix that

Comment: is there no other way ,i mean any workaround to force al intents globally

Comment: @Lenoarod,Could you please explain more...i know about reflection,but how to modify the intents

Comment: think it like general object, modify it property before you call that.

Comment: see this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966726/how-to-change-method-behaviour-through-reflection